# How can i pass an instance's constructor as a type to a function

Tags: dart

I am trying to create a base class for my models but I am struggling with the error `The name 'cls' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.`. So, how can I pass the object's constructor to the Hive.box method?

```dart
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

class AppModel {
  @HiveField(0)
  int id;

  @HiveField(1)
  DateTime createdAt;

  @HiveField(2)
  DateTime updatedAt;

  save() async {
    final Type cls = this.runtimeType;
    // The name 'cls' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
    final Box box = await Hive.openBox<cls>(cls.toString());

    await box.put(this.id, this);

    return this;
  }
}

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class UserModel extends AppModel {
  @HiveField(3)
  String email;

  @HiveField(4)
  String displayName;
}

void main() {
  final UserModel user = UserModel()
    ..email = 'user@domain.com'
    ..displayName = 'john doe';

  user.save().then(() {
    print('saved');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart does not have a way to refer to the dynamic type of `this` (a "self type").

The way such things are often handled is to have a self-type as type argument, so:

```dart
class AppModel<T extends AppModel> {
  save() async {
    final Box box = await Hive.openBox<T>(T.toString());
    await box.put(this.id, this as T);
    return this;
  }
  ...
```

and then ensure that each subclass tells the superclass what type it is:

```dart
class UserModel extends AppModel<UserModel> {
  ...
}
```

(or, if you expect to subclass `UserModel` eventually:

```dart
class UserModel<T extends UserModel> extends AppModel<T> {
   ...
}
```

so that a subclass can still pass its type through).

You are also talking about constructors, and for that there is no easy solution.
Dart's type parameters are *types*, not *classes*. You cannot access static members or constructors from a type variable, and there is also no other way to pass a class around.

The only way you can have something call a constructor that it doesn't refer to statically, is to wrap the constructor call in a function and pass that function.
(I can't see how you need the constructor here).